# CakePHP saveField -- beforeSave has no effect? (2.4.3)

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I am 99% sure this must be a User error (because otherwise I am sure thousands of users would have posted that they are experiencing this problem) but I cannot figure out what is causing it!

I have the following code in Model:

```
public function setProductPackagingId($id, $product_packaging_id)
{
    $this->id = $id;
    return $this->saveField('product_packaging_id', $product_packaging_id);
}

public function beforeSave()
{       
    $this->data[$this->alias]['version'] = 2;
    debug($this->data);
    return true;
}

public function afterSave($created, $options)
{
    debug($options);
}
```

When I execute the function setProductPackagingId(), beforeSave fires and debug($this->data) returns:

```
array(
'PurchaseOrderProduct' => array(
    'id' => (int) 1,
    'product_packaging_id' => (int) 54,
    'version' => (int) 1000
  )
)
```

However the SQL generated by CakePHP is only:

```
UPDATE `roving_tms`.`purchase_order_products` SET `product_packaging_id` = 54  WHERE `roving_tms`.`purchase_order_products`.`id` = 1
```

So, my version field added in beforeSave was missed somehow in the generated SQL?

Also, debug($options) in afterSave returns:

```
array(
'validate' => false,
'fieldList' => array(
    (int) 0 => 'product_packaging_id'
),
'callbacks' => true,
'counterCache' => true
)
```

However, if I modify setProductPackagingId to the following:

```
public function setProductPackagingId($id, $product_packaging_id)
{   
    $purchase_order_product = array(
            'PurchaseOrderProduct' => array(
                    'id' => $id,
                    'product_packaging_id' => $product_packaging_id
                    ));

    return $this->save($purchase_order_product);
}
```

debug($this->data); in beforeSave() produces the same output as before.

However, the SQL produced is:

```
UPDATE `roving_tms`.`purchase_order_products` SET `id` = 1, `product_packaging_id` = 54, `version` = 1000  WHERE `roving_tms`.`purchase_order_products`.`id` = 1
```

(version is included, which is what I wanted)

And debug($options) in afterSave() produces:

```
array(
'validate' => true,
'fieldList' => array(),
'callbacks' => true,
'counterCache' => true
```

)

The only differences I can see here is that in the case where 'saveField()' was used, afterSave $options['fieldlist'] contained the parameter 'product_packaging_id'.
However, when called from save(), $options['fieldlist'] was blank.

Is there something really obvious and stupid I am doing here which is stopping beforeSave from working correctly with saveField? Or is this the desired outcome in CakePHP?
If I need to use beforeSave with saveField, am I supposed to execute another db update directly from within beforeSave (this sounds like a dumb idea for db I/O reasons). Or, do I somehow need to manually edit the 'fieldList' parameter so the other fields I want edited will actually be edited?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**CakePHP's [saveField()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-savefield-string-fieldname-string-fieldvalue-validate-false) is used to save a single field.**

That being said, why would Cake generate a query and include a different field that has nothing to do with the only field you specifically told it to save?

The answer is, it doesn't - it builds the query to update the only field you told it to. If you passed 20 fields with your data, then called `saveField()`, it would still only generate the query to update the field you specified, and completely ignore the rest of the data, regardless of whether it's in the initial data or added during `beforeSave()`.

> ```
> "Used to save a single field value."
> ```

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-savefield-string-fieldname-string-fieldvalue-validate-false

Comment: I understand it is used to update a single field, however it is not explicitly stated that you cannot manipulate other fields via beforeSave. I was (falsely) under the impression it was simply a short-hand for performing a regular save() operation upon a single field. Perhaps this information should be provided in the beforeSave() api, because I would expect that if the beforeSave function executes, it should perform as per usual.

Comment: No, it is there, read the whole documentation of a method: callbacks Set to false to disable callbacks. Using ‘before’ or ‘after’ will enable only those callbacks.

Comment: @burzum what do you mean? The callback is being executed it's just that the code you write inside the callback has a different effect depending on whether it was called from save() or saveField().

Comment: Cakephp is generating an SQL to try and update other fields. In my case. Even thou I try to update one, it comes back with an error for not null on a completely different field. Time to move to a good framework.

Comment: @RonaldoSantana - like any framework, if you don't understand it, and do things wrong, you'll get the wrong results.  Luckily, CakePHP has a TON of free online information, tutorials, documentation...etc.